# Install package in the dockerfile

Tags: docker, .net-core, docker-compose, ffmpeg, dockerfile

Below is dockerfile with installation details of ffmpeg.

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/aspnet:3.1-buster-slim AS base

RUN sed -i 's/deb.debian.org/mirrors.ustc.edu.cn/g' /etc/apt/sources.list \
    && apt-get update \
    && apt-get install -y ffmpeg \
    && apt-get clean && apt-get autoclean && apt-get autoremove \
    && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y libgdiplus libc6-dev && ln -s /usr/lib/libgdiplus.so /usr/lib/gdiplus.dll
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 80
EXPOSE 443
...
```

How can I install different ffmpeg package, more specifically [`alfg/ffmpeg`](https://hub.docker.com/r/alfg/ffmpeg/)
in that way to preserve the rest of the dockerfile intact and with same installation path `/usr/bin/ffmpeg`.

## EDIT

Here's my Dockerfile

```
#See https://aka.ms/containerfastmode to understand how Visual Studio uses this Dockerfile to build your images for faster debugging.
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:6.0 AS build

ARG FFMPEG_VERSION=4.4

ARG PREFIX=/opt/ffmpeg
ARG LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/opt/ffmpeg/lib
ARG MAKEFLAGS="-j4"

# FFmpeg build dependencies.
RUN apk add --update \
  build-base \
  coreutils \
  freetype-dev \
  gcc \
  lame-dev \
  libogg-dev \
  libass \
  libass-dev \
  libvpx-dev \
  libvorbis-dev \
  libwebp-dev \
  libtheora-dev \
  opus-dev \
  openssl \
  openssl-dev \
  pkgconf \
  pkgconfig \
  rtmpdump-dev \
  wget \
  x264-dev \
  x265-dev \
  yasm

# Get fdk-aac from community.
RUN echo http://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/edge/community >> /etc/apk/repositories && \
  apk add --update fdk-aac-dev

# Get rav1e from testing.
RUN echo http://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/edge/testing >> /etc/apk/repositories && \
  apk add --update rav1e-dev

# Get ffmpeg source.
RUN cd /tmp/ && \
  wget http://ffmpeg.org/releases/ffmpeg-${FFMPEG_VERSION}.tar.gz && \
  tar zxf ffmpeg-${FFMPEG_VERSION}.tar.gz && rm ffmpeg-${FFMPEG_VERSION}.tar.gz

# Compile ffmpeg.
RUN cd /tmp/ffmpeg-${FFMPEG_VERSION} && \
  ./configure \
  --enable-version3 \
  --enable-gpl \
  --enable-nonfree \
  --enable-small \
  --enable-libmp3lame \
  --enable-libx264 \
  --enable-libx265 \
  --enable-libvpx \
  --enable-libtheora \
  --enable-libvorbis \
  --enable-libopus \
  --enable-libfdk-aac \
  --enable-libass \
  --enable-libwebp \
  --enable-librtmp \
  --enable-librav1e \
  --enable-postproc \
  --enable-libfreetype \
  --enable-openssl \
  --disable-debug \
  --disable-doc \
  --disable-ffplay \
  --extra-cflags="-I${PREFIX}/include" \
  --extra-ldflags="-L${PREFIX}/lib" \
  --extra-libs="-lpthread -lm" \
  --prefix="${PREFIX}" && \
  make && make install && make distclean

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:6.0
ENV PATH=/opt/ffmpeg/bin:$PATH

RUN apk add --update \
  ca-certificates \
  openssl \
  pcre \
  lame \
  libogg \
  libass \
  libvpx \
  libvorbis \
  libwebp \
  libtheora \
  opus \
  rtmpdump \
  x264-dev \
  x265-dev

COPY --from=build /opt/ffmpeg /opt/ffmpeg
COPY --from=build /usr/lib/libfdk-aac.so.2 /usr/lib/libfdk-aac.so.2
COPY --from=build /usr/lib/librav1e.so /usr/lib/librav1e.so

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y libgdiplus libc6-dev && ln -s /usr/lib/libgdiplus.so /usr/lib/gdiplus.dll

WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 80
EXPOSE 49154
ENV ASPNETCORE_URLS=http://+:49154

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:6.0 AS build
WORKDIR /src
COPY ["CarPrjP/CarPrjP.csproj", "CarPrjP/"]
RUN dotnet restore "CarPrjP/CarPrjP.csproj"
COPY . .
WORKDIR "/src/CarPrjP"
RUN dotnet build "CarPrjP.csproj" -c Release -o /app/build

FROM build AS publish
RUN dotnet publish "CarPrjP.csproj" -c Release -o /app/publish

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app/publish .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "CarPrjP.dll"]
```

not sure with this changes what is the path for ffmpe binaries. With the old Dockerfile (1st in this example) it worked fine (when it comes to finding ffmpeg binaries). It was referenced from the code like this

```
string ffmpegPath = "/usr/bin/ffmpeg";
string ffprobePath = "/usr/bin/ffprobe";
```

Now with new dockerfile I'm getting

> System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception: 'An error occurred trying to
> start process '/usr/bin/ffmpeg' with working directory '/app'. No such
> file or directory
> Obviously I need to change path to match the new installation path, tried with /opt/ffmpeg but that doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find the Dockerfile for their build here https://github.com/alfg/docker-ffmpeg/blob/master/Dockerfile.

Maybe you can copy parts of their dockerfile into yours.

Here's my attempt. I switched your aspnet image to alpine since the ffmpeg dockerfile is alpine and changing package managers seemed like a big task.

```
FROM alpine:3.14 as build

ARG FFMPEG_VERSION=4.4

ARG PREFIX=/opt/ffmpeg
ARG LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/opt/ffmpeg/lib
ARG MAKEFLAGS="-j4"

# FFmpeg build dependencies.
RUN apk add --update \
  build-base \
  coreutils \
  freetype-dev \
  gcc \
  lame-dev \
  libogg-dev \
  libass \
  libass-dev \
  libvpx-dev \
  libvorbis-dev \
  libwebp-dev \
  libtheora-dev \
  opus-dev \
  openssl \
  openssl-dev \
  pkgconf \
  pkgconfig \
  rtmpdump-dev \
  wget \
  x264-dev \
  x265-dev \
  yasm

# Get fdk-aac from community.
RUN echo http://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/edge/community >> /etc/apk/repositories && \
  apk add --update fdk-aac-dev

# Get rav1e from testing.
RUN echo http://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/edge/testing >> /etc/apk/repositories && \
  apk add --update rav1e-dev

# Get ffmpeg source.
RUN cd /tmp/ && \
  wget http://ffmpeg.org/releases/ffmpeg-${FFMPEG_VERSION}.tar.gz && \
  tar zxf ffmpeg-${FFMPEG_VERSION}.tar.gz && rm ffmpeg-${FFMPEG_VERSION}.tar.gz

# Compile ffmpeg.
RUN cd /tmp/ffmpeg-${FFMPEG_VERSION} && \
  ./configure \
  --enable-version3 \
  --enable-gpl \
  --enable-nonfree \
  --enable-small \
  --enable-libmp3lame \
  --enable-libx264 \
  --enable-libx265 \
  --enable-libvpx \
  --enable-libtheora \
  --enable-libvorbis \
  --enable-libopus \
  --enable-libfdk-aac \
  --enable-libass \
  --enable-libwebp \
  --enable-librtmp \
  --enable-librav1e \
  --enable-postproc \
  --enable-libfreetype \
  --enable-openssl \
  --disable-debug \
  --disable-doc \
  --disable-ffplay \
  --extra-cflags="-I${PREFIX}/include" \
  --extra-ldflags="-L${PREFIX}/lib" \
  --extra-libs="-lpthread -lm" \
  --prefix="${PREFIX}" && \
  make && make install && make distclean

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/aspnet:3.1-alpine
ENV PATH=/opt/ffmpeg/bin:$PATH

RUN apk add --update \
  ca-certificates \
  openssl \
  pcre \
  lame \
  libogg \
  libass \
  libvpx \
  libvorbis \
  libwebp \
  libtheora \
  opus \
  rtmpdump \
  x264-dev \
  x265-dev

COPY --from=build /opt/ffmpeg /opt/ffmpeg
COPY --from=build /usr/lib/libfdk-aac.so.2 /usr/lib/libfdk-aac.so.2
COPY --from=build /usr/lib/librav1e.so /usr/lib/librav1e.so
```

Build and run

```
docker build -t test .
docker run --rm test /bin/sh -c "ffmpeg -version; dotnet --list-runtimes"
```

Comment: Actually, I thought I'll be able to replace just this section `RUN sed -i`  inside my docker file.  I guess I don't know docker that well. Can you please provide the steps I need to take in order to install `alfg/docker-ffmpeg`. Thank  you

Comment: I've tried fiddling around with it, but I can't get it to work :(

Comment: Thanks anyway, in case you have time post whenever. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: @user1765862 I got it to work and have updated my answer